# How to call webservice in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a webservice in .NET and I need to call that webservice with methods from a Windows Phone 7 app. I don't have any idea about development for Windows Phone 7. I just started 2 days ago. So please help me. I've searched and tried with many links, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: knowing how you're developing would help (I can guess C#). Also knowing which kind of WS you're attempting to call would be usefull (.NET service? Java Service? arbitrary SOAP web service ?) ANd is WS-Security involved ? and I can probably go on with question for days...

Comment: i am using C#.I am attempting to call .NET webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by looking up some articles and tutorials on development for Windows Phone 7 to get familiar with the platform. [**MSDN Code Samples**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) can be found here, they're pretty basic but good enough to get you on the way. After that you could do a quick Google search for "*windows phone 7 web services*". One of the results is [**this article**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/UrmimalaPal/creating-a-windows-phone-7-application-consuming-data-using-a-wcf-service/) explaining how to make and consume a webservice. I hope this helps you get started!

Answer (score 1):

This is the best available video tutorial.. 
[Webservices for Windows Phone 7 in 7 mins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/gg241261)

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say Consuming Web Service.

If it is based on SOAP then you can add Service reference into your project by providing the Service API link and it generates the automatic classes for you.

For Restful service you can use HTTP Client or Web Client to make the API call and you can get the response on call back functions.

Hope Its Trivial answer